# Clicking first tr of table with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a table of notes that I want to test.

```
<table class="table" ng-if="!NotesCtrl.loadingNotes && (NotesCtrl.notes | filter: { client : ClientCtrl.client.id }).length">
    <tr class="noteTableItem" ng-repeat="note in NotesCtrl.notes | filter: { client : ClientCtrl.client.id } track by note.id" ng-click="NotesCtrl.showNote(note.id)">
        <td>{{ note.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ note.created | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy - HH:mm' }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I write a test to see if there is only 1 row, it passes:

```
it('should see one note-item', function(){
    var notes = element.all(by.css('.noteTableItem'));
    expect(notes.count()).toEqual(1);
});
```

When I then want to click on the first note, to trigger the `ng-click`, it fails with the message:

```
it('should click the first item', function(){
    var notes = element.all(by.css('.noteTableItem'));
    expect(notes.count()).toEqual(1);
    notes.first().click();
    expect(noteDialog.isDisplayed());
});
```

> Failed: Element `<tr class="noteTableItem ng-scope">` could not be scrolled into view

How can I click the first item with **Protractor** ? (When I work with a list `<ul></ul>`, it **does** work...)

Comment: Your code is correct, so the cause should from browser and webdriver.  What browser and version you used, and what version of webdriver you used.

Comment: Protractor 5.3.0 - webdriver-manager 12.0.6 - Firefox

Comment: If I use Chrome, indeed it works...

Comment: What's your Firefox version and geckodriver version?

Answer (score 0):

Try with xpath:

```
element(by.xpath("//table/tr/td[0]")).click();
```

or

```
$$("table tr td").get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use executeScript method(native javaScript) like below to scroll the object in the view:

```
 var elem= element(locatorCss('Locator definition'));
 browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem.getWebElement()).then(function(){
     elem.click().then(function () {
        console.log("Object Clicked!!!");
      });
  });
```